# Content-Security-Policy - Can't load external scripts

Tags: javascript, html, content-security-policy

for a private Project I want to load some external images, scripts and styles from my homeserver, but it doesnt work. Where is the mistake?

Nginx Config-File

```
location / {
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            server_tokens off;
            add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
            add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
            add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
            add_header Content-Security-Policy  "default-src *; script-src *; object-src *; style-src *; img-src *; media-src *; frame-src *; font-src *; connect-src *";
            add_header X-Content-Security-Policy "default-src *; script-src *; object-src *; style-src *; img-src *; media-src *; frame-src *; font-src *; connect-src *";
            add_header X-WebKit-CSP "default-src *; script-src *; object-src *; style-src *; img-src *; media-src *; frame-src *; font-src *; connect-src *";

}
```

HTML Meta Tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src *; style-src *; img-src *; font-src *; connect-src *; media-src *; object-src *; prefetch-src *; child-src *; frame-src *; worker-src *; frame-ancestors *; form-action *; sandbox allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-popups allow-pointer-lock; reflected-xss allow; base-uri *; manifest-src *;" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src *; object-src *; style-src *; img-src *; media-src *; frame-src *; font-src *; connect-src *">
    <meta http-equiv="X-WebKit-CSP" content= "default-src *; script-src *; object-src *; style-src *; img-src *; media-src *; frame-src *; font-src *; connect-src *">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem the is in that `*` matches only to network scheme URLs (http/https/ftp etc). So you can

1. Add network scheme URL to policy (like `myserver.com`)
2. Add `cdvfile:` into your policy

I would made one single `default-src` with your homeserver URL and remove all other sources. If you want to allow load content only from same origin you should set your CSP sources to `'self'` (in case if your project hosted on your homeserver).

Most of CSP directives in your config are redundant, for example: you should remove `base-uri` if you want to allow any URIs as base URI for your site. I recommend to review every directive to gain necessary result. There is a good memo for CSP: https://content-security-policy.com/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it must be flexible, later I want to you use it for more IP's and different scenarios. The URL is http://IPADRESS/index.php, would this not be in accordance with the scheme?